Injecting REQUEST in my Service in NestJS breaks jwt
I am trying it inject request in my AuthService which uses jwt. Without the inject everything work fine I am able to authenticate and flow is working. As soon as I inject request (or any other thing) I get Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private readonly logger = new Logger('AuthService');

    constructor(
        private readonly settingService: SettingService,
        private readonly tokenService: AccessTokenService,
        private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
        @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
    ) { }
}


This is documented, and there's a way to work around it

@JayMcDoniel first of all thank your for the comment it solved what I was looking for but after implementing this I faced another issue with request object being undefined, you can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78812051/nestjs-multitenancy-with-passport-jwt-not-working-request-object-is-undefined
