NestJS multitenancy with Passport JWT not working, Request object is undefined
I have created a multitenant app in NestJs using a connection factory where we inject a connection for each request. I have spent several days debugging this but no luck till now.
Github repository: https://github.com/mhira-project/mhira-backend/tree/feature/multitenancy
This is the connection factory
export const connectionFactory = {
    provide: CONNECTION,
    scope: Scope.REQUEST,
    useFactory: (request: Request) => {
        console.log('request', request)
        if (!request) {
            throw new Error('Request object is undefined');
        }
        const { subdomain } = request.req;
        if (subdomain) {
            return getTenantConnection(subdomain);
        }

        return null;
    },
    inject: [REQUEST],
};

@Global()
@Module({
    providers: [connectionFactory],
    exports: [CONNECTION],
})
export class TenancyModule { }

This is validate method in my JwtStrategy
async validate(req: Request, payload: any): Promise<any> {
    const { jti } = payload;
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(req);
    this.authService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(AuthService, contextId);

    try {
        const user = await this.authService.validateAccessToken(jti);
        console.log('here')
        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error validating access token:', error);
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}

I never see the here console because the request object in connectionFactory is undefined. I have logged the request there and I can see in my console that first time request is logged correctly, I get the subdomain and then the connection is fine but I don't know why when I call validateAccessToken the connectionFactory is called again but now the request is undefined.
This is happening only after user is logged in, the login functionality works as expected.

seems to be related to how the request object is being handled and passed through the connection factory, especially during the JWT validation process.

Use the REQUEST injection token properly to ensure it gets the
correct request object for each HTTP request.
Modify your connection factory to use ExecutionContext from the NestJS context; you can reliably get request object.

Connection Factory
import { Injectable, Scope, ExecutionContext, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class ConnectionFactory {
    constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}

    getConnection() {
        if (!this.request) {
            throw new Error('Req obj is undefined');
        }
        const { subdomain } = this.request;
        if (subdomain) {
            return getTenantConnection(subdomain);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

export const connectionFactory = {
    provide: CONNECTION,
    useFactory: (factory: ConnectionFactory) => factory.getConnection(),
    inject: [ConnectionFactory],
};

JWT Strategy
import { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ContextIdFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

async validate(context: ExecutionContext, payload: any): Promise<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
    const { jti } = payload;
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(request);
    this.authService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(AuthService, contextId);

    try {
        const user = await this.authService.validateAccessToken(jti);
        console.log('here');
        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error happened while accesing the token:', error);
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}


The problem with this is that context: ExecutionContext is wrong as in the first parameter of the validate method from passport we already get the HTTP request not the ExecutionContext.

Here is also a reference mentionin this: https://github.com/nestjs/passport/issues/8

I have also the repository here: https://github.com/mhira-project/mhira-backend/tree/feature/multitenancy
